# Why does the Fifth Ode (Prayer of Isaiah) begin at verse 9 and end at verse 20?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, liturgy-of-the-hours, septuagint

Ode 5 in the LXX Book of Odes, and in the canon at Byzantine Orthros/Matins, starts at Isaiah 26:9. Why does it skip the first nine verses which open with the introduction making it clear the whole chapter is a song? (‘In that day shall this song be sung in the land of Judah: We have a strong city (etc.)’) And why are the last two/three verses of the chapter not sung?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately because [chapters and verse divisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapters_and_verses_of_the_Bible) are a relatively novel invention, and do not form a part of the original biblical text, Greek or otherwise; as such, what you call *the first nine verses* are neither *first* (because there is an entire ocean of text lying before them, corresponding to roughly a third of the whole book of Isaiah), nor *nine*, nor *verses* (because, along with chapters, they simply did not exist *as such* at the time the *Odes* were selected); thus, you are [anachronistically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism) imposing a far later structure or convention unto an otherwise undivided text, by thinking that there is even a chapter to begin with, and, not only that, but that it should start at a specified location, decided centuries, or even millennia, after their selection.

Furthermore, the main purpose of these pious [liturgical hymns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liturgy_of_the_Hours) or prayers is to be said at [certain specific times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_hours), such as evenings, or mornings, or afternoons, by the faithful; thus, that the aforementioned text starts with the words

> <sup>(26:9)</sup> My soul yearns for you in the *night*;
>
> in the *morning* my spirit longs for you.

makes perfect sense; similarly for its ending, which reads:

> <sup>(26:20)</sup> enter your rooms
>
> and shut the doors behind you;
>
> hide yourselves for a little while

which is pretty much what normal people do when they go to bed at night. Lending deep, mystical, and philosophical meanings to such common human activities is also a nice touch:

> <sup>(26:19)</sup> your dead will live, Lord; their *bodies* will *rise*—
>
> let those who dwell in the dust *wake up* and shout for joy—
>
> your *dew* is like the *dew* of the *morning*

It is not entirely clear how adding any of the preceding or succeeding verses improves these perfectly chosen endpoints; if anything, the chapter's last verse seems more befitting of the next very chapter, which follows along similar lines, rather than matching the main theme of the selected portion:

> <sup>(26:21)</sup> the Lord is coming out of his dwelling
>
> to *punish* the people of the earth for their sins.
>
> The earth will disclose the *blood shed* on it;
>
> the earth will conceal its *slain* no longer.
>
> <sup>(27:1)</sup> the Lord will *punish* with his *sword*—
>
> (...) he will *slay* the monster of the sea.